# Scala: simple HelloWorld does not run after compiling to Java class

Tags: scala

Code:

```
object HelloWorld{
    def main(args: Array[String]){
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Environment Variables:

On windows:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07
CLASSPATH = .;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\lib;C:\Software\scala-2.9.2\lib
PATH = %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07\bin;C:\Software\scala-2.9.2\bin
SCALA_HOME = C:\Software\scala-2.9.2
```

Steps:

```
scala HelloWorld.scala  //Correctly output Hello,world!
scalac HelloWorld.scala //No Compilation error
java HelloWorld  //Errors shown below
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/ScalaObject
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at HelloWorld.main(HelloWorld.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.ScalaObject
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 13 more
```

Sorry for the noobie question, but I have tried for a long time and could not get it work.

Tried `scala -save` to jar file and run `java -jar`; also tried change classpath like adding `scala-library.jar`, and still not working.

Comment: you need to set scala library jar on classpath to run with `java` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me (Linux):

```
java -cp scala-library-2.9.1.jar:. HelloWorld
```

[`scala-library-2.9.1.jar` can be found here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/scala-lang/scala-library/2.9.1/scala-library-2.9.1.jar).

On Windows you have to use semicolon as CLASSPATH separator:

```
java -cp scala-library-2.9.1.jar;. HelloWorld
```

Basically you need to add both `scala-library-*.jar` JAR *and* `.class` files with your code. In the examples above is simply use `.` to denote `.class` files in current directory.

Comment: I have `C:\Software\scala-2.9.2\lib` in my class path, and also I tried using your way it was not working. I already said it in the bottom of the question.

Comment: The jar file itself must be in the classpath, not just the directory containing it, so: CLASSPATH=.;C:\Software\scala-2.9.2\lib\scala-library-2.9.2.jar;

Comment: It works now. So do I have to put all jar files in the CLASSPATH?

Comment: @texasbruce: in your simple example adding `scala-library.jar` alone is enough. But in general - yes.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz It is a great pain if there are hundreds of them :(

Comment: @texasbruce: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/219585/setting-multiple-jars-in-java-classpath and check out maven (it can greatly help)

Answer (score 0):

> It is a great pain if there are hundreds of them :(

It is not, you just put them jars in your #JRE#/lib/ext directory